# Is there anyway to access a listing of all PHP variables?

Tags: php, memory, variables

I created a singleton registry to contain instances of all my objects, and I try to unset variables when they are no longer in use. However, I can't seem to ever find *all* of the variables in use. There always seems to be a couple hundred KB that I *can't explain* floating around...

I'm not sure it this is possible, but can you access an internal variable listing in PHP somewhere? That would sure help with code audits to keep things clean and working fast.

I tried looking through xdebug and [xdebug_debug_zval_stdout](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display) seemed to be the closest thing to tracking references and more detailed variable information - but it can't guess what values are already out there.

Comment: Remember that PHP keeps its own internal caches of strings etc. This confused me once trying to do a memory profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
 var_dump(get_defined_vars());
?>
```

Comment: Remember to use this in each variable scope - but it works great!